# How to prevent duplicate file upload using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, duplicates, paperclip

In rails 4 project I am using paperclip gem to upload files. I want to avoid duplicate file uploads. How can i check if the file uploaded is duplicate? Also I want to change the name of uploaded file while saving. How can I do this?

Gem which I am using is provided below

```
paperclip (3.5.2, 2.3.11, 2.3.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name of the file you are uploading, add this in development.rb and production.rb with the options that you want.

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :url => "/posts/:id.:extension",
    :path => "#{Rails.root}/public/posts/:id.:extension",
  }
```

To get the filename after uploading, you can use:

```
File.basename(model.avatar.path)
```

To prevent duplicates, store the [checksum (read more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784585/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-if-files-are-identical) of your uploaded file in a separate column. On new attachment, compare the checksum of the new one with the existing rows.

Comment: While saving I need to update the document_file_name field. Example : I am uploading abc.doc file, while saving the document_file_name should change to xyz.doc file.

Comment: @shubhra thats not needed. to get the filename, check my updated answer

Comment: How do I implement checksum? Is there any other way?