# Why isn't random byte comparison a good method of testing equality?

Tags: performance, random, hash

I have two 50G+ files I want to compare for equality.

'`diff -a`' or '`cmp`' would work, but are slow.

Hashing both files and comparing the hashes would be faster(?), but 
still fairly slow.

Instead, suppose I randomly selected 10,000 numbers between 1 and 50G, 
and compared those specific bytes in the two files, using seek() for speed.

I claim the chance 10,000 randomly selected bytes will match in the 
two files by coincidence is about 256^10000 to 1 (or about 1 in 
10^2408).

This makes it orders of magnitude better than any known hash function, 
and much faster.

So, what's wrong with this argument? Why isn't random byte testing 
superior to hashing?

This question inspired by:

[What is the fastest way to check if files are identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784585/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-if-files-are-identical)

(where I suggest a similar, but slightly different method)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you have an accidental bit flip somewhere in there?  Even just one would be enough to make your checks fail

Answer (score 0):

Your odds calculation is only true if the two files themselves contain random bytes, which is almost certainly not the case. Two large files of the same size on the same system are very likely to be highly correlated.  For example, on my system now there are three files of the same size in 8GB range--they are raw dumps of SD cards representing different versions of the same software, so it is likely that only a few hundred bytes of them are different. The same would apply to, say, two database snapshots from consecutive days.

Because large files differing by only a few bytes is a very possible--indeed likely--case, you really have no choice but to read every byte of both. Hashing will at least save you from comparing every byte.

One thing you might be able to do is access the blocks in each file in a pre-determined pseudo-ramdom order to maximize the likelihood of finding the small patch of difference and being able to abort early on failure.